# How to find build derived objects from a changeset of files?

Tags: windows, build

I can use `git diff` to get a list of files changed between two commits (a change set).

Is there a way (tool or commands preferably usable on Windows) to calculate what derived objects get created when a file in that change set is built?

E.g. if a `.cs` file is in the changeset what `dll` or `exe` will that build into?

Basically how do you determine what binaries / derived objects (I think I'm using the correct term) to include in an installer in a Git / Windows environment?

Comment: I don't think this is really a Git question. The linking of source code to binaries will depend heavily on the build environment you have set up. Git can show you which files were changed in a commit, but not what binaries would be built. (If you're asking how to find the files changed in a commit *and* how to link those files to the relevant binaries, then this should be [split into two separate questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/269535).)

Comment: Hi Scott - I am only interested in how to link files to relevant binaries. We used to use clearaudit for this but now i need an alternative. Thanks